# Writing Async code in event driven way

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, asynchronous, event-driven-design

I am programminfg in `node.js` sometimes async functions become really incredibly dirty.
I want to write async code but retrieve data as an event happens i am aware of promises but it is not exactly what i want simply what i ask is something like this

```
asyncFunc(error,dt,ld){
//some async code such as db operations
}
```

then i want to fetchj the data in event way

```
asyncFunc.on("dt",function(dt){do something});
asyncFunc.on("error",function(err){i have an error object});
asyncFunc.on("ld",function(ls){loading});
```

is there any way to do this i know promises and some 3rd party libraries against callback hell but my question is especially in that way i wrote how i can design my code ?

Comment: You can do this by having your async code check for all 3 situations when your async code resolves. Eg, let's pretend you're doing an ajax call. When the call returns the data (or an error), you'll have to check for each event you support and warn your event mediator about it. If it returns an error, trigger the 'error' event, if it returns data, trigger the 'dt' event etc. Personally, I switched to promises after getting fed up with keeping app state consistent through multiple event calls.

Comment: how i will trigger an event i am not sure about that can you please write as answer with example i can select as solution then

Comment: The answer below contains a nice example of the builtin node mediator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nodejs events

```
var asyncFunc = function(error,dt,ld){
    var events = require('events');
    var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

    //emit error
    eventEmitter.emit('error', new Error('some error'));
    //emit dt
    eventEmitter.emit('dt', 'some data for dt');
    //emit dld
    eventEmitter.emit('ld', {message: 'some details for ld', ld: ld});
    return eventEmitter;
}

//then
asyncFunc.on("dt",function(dt){/*do something*/});
asyncFunc.on("error",function(err){/*i have an error object*/});
asyncFunc.on("ld",function(ls){/*loading*/});
```

Great article [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/)

Official nodejs [event docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Comment: this is the solution i guess but still have some questions :) how i can return multipple values for one event and can i return object for example for loading let it be a file upload sometyhing like on("ld",function(expected,received))

Comment: you cannot return multiple values, but you can wrap them into single object. as in third emit i wrote